# Passing this as a parameter

Tags: java, parameters, this, keyword

I've seen code that have passed the keyword `this` as an input parameter.
**For instance:**

```
getContainer(this);
```

What does the keyword `this` mean? I've heard that it refers to an instance of the class itself (or something along those lines), but how does that work?

Comment: This is an argument and not a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

[From 15.8.3 of the java specification:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.8.3)

> The keyword this may be used only in the body of an instance method,
>   instance initializer or constructor, or in the initializer of an
>   instance variable of a class. If it appears anywhere else, a
>   compile-time error occurs. When used as a primary expression, the
>   keyword this denotes a value that is a reference to the object for
>   which the instance method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being
>   constructed. The type of this is the class C within which the keyword
>   this occurs. At run time, the class of the actual object referred to
>   may be the class C or any subclass of C.
>
> [...]
>
> The keyword this is also used in a special explicit constructor
>   invocation statement, which can appear at the beginning of a
>   constructor body (§8.8.7).

So yeah, a class can use the this keyword to refer to itself. The `this` keyword is also required when a local variable within a method has the same name as a class member variable, to distinguish them both.

Answer (score 3):

`this` can also be passed to pass the instance of the calling class to the called class. 
for example

```
public class Caller{
        public void callerClassMethod1(){
            new Called(this).
        }

        public void callerClassMethod2(){
        }
    }

class Called{
    private Caller caller;
    public Called(Caller caller){
       this.caller=caller;
    }
    public void calledClassMethod1(){
        //.... Do something before
        caller.callerClassMethod2();
        //..... Do something after        

    }
}
```

This way you can separate the responsibilities of the 2 classes and at the same time keep them coupled.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to current instance on which method has been invoked,

So it passes the reference to current instance invoking that member method

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    public MyRunnable() {
        this.t = new Thread(this); //here it passes reference to current instance of `Runnable`
    }

    public void run() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In java we have classes and create instances (objects) of those classes. So when the object needs to point or reference itself  then the **this** keyword is used.